# Automatic update of module/connector dependencies in POM file - Mule 4

Tags: maven, mule, pom.xml

When we import the Mule 3 project into the latest version of Anypoint studio, I see that a few of the module dependencies aren't recognized automatically and those components are not fully enabled for editing/viewing configuration. To resolve this, I'm updating the POM file manually to point to the latest version of the module available in Anypoint studio. Modules like Salesforce, Validation.., etc all are having this issue.

Is there a way to automatically update the POM file once we import the project into Anypoint Studio, without manually editing that?.

Answer (score 1):

Not in Anypoint Studio 6, which is the only compatible with Mule 3 projects.

Anypoint Studio 7, which is only compatible with Mule 4 projects, has [update module/connectors features](https://docs.mulesoft.com/studio/7.11/update-modules) builtin. While you can not use Studio 7 for Mule 3 projects, if you decide to migrate be sure to use the last release of Studio 7.